# How can I find these two limits?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

How can I find these two limits? I've no idea how to improve or continue now. Can someone give me a hint?

1)$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{\cos^{\pi}(25x)} {\tan^3(x)}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\cos^{\pi} (25x)\cot^3(x))$$

2)$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\left(\frac{\cos^{\pi}(25x)} {\tan^3(x)}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0^-} (\cos^{\pi} (25x)\cot^3(x))$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The numerator approaches a positive number and the denominator approaches $0$, from above in the first case and from below in the second case.  That's all you need to know in order to deal with these. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1)$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{\cos^{\pi}(25x)} {\tan^3(x)}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\cos^{\pi} (25x)\cot^3(x))$$ $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left((\cos^{\pi}(25x)\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\right)^3\right)=$$ $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\cos^{\pi}(25x)\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\right)^3=$$ $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\cos^{\pi}(25x)\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)^3}\right)=$$ $$1^{\pi}(\infty)=\infty$$

2)$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\left(\frac{\cos^{\pi}(25x)} {\tan^3(x)}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0^-} (\cos^{\pi} (25x)\cot^3(x))=$$ $$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\left((\cos^{\pi}(25x)\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\right)^3\right)=$$ $$\lim_{x \to 0^-}(\cos^{\pi}(25x)\lim_{x \to 0^-}\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\right)^3=$$ $$\lim_{x \to 0^-}(\cos^{\pi}(25x)\lim_{x \to 0^-}\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)^3}\right)=$$ $$1^{\pi}(-\infty)=-\infty$$